# Как правильно сделать синхронизацию?

Tags: java, синхронизация

Практикуюсь работать с синхронизацией потоков и не получается сделать так, как придумал. У меня есть аккаунт в банке, муж и жена кладут туда деньги. Я хочу сделать так, чтоб они по очереди это делали. Я делаю это так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Wife().start();
        new Husband().start();
    }
}

public class Husband extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Husband " + i + " " +   Account.deposit());
        }
    }
}

public class Wife extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Wife " + i + " " + Account.deposit());
        }
    }
}

public class Account {
    public synchronized static int deposit(){
        account += 300;
        return account;
    }
}
```

Но все равно получается бардак. Может вместо `synchronized` нужно семафоры использовать? Чтоб была правильная очередность.

Comment: шоб по очереди делали - вроде бы у `wife` и `husband` в методах `run` достаточно написать `Account.deposit()` а в `main`  написать цикл `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { wife.start.... husband.start.....husband.join()  }` ......... вот пример https://ideone.com/Fqe5g8

Comment: А зачем создание потока запихивать в цикл, он же будет 10 раз создавать новый поток... Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: а что страшного тут?))) создал поток, он быстро отработал, сдох......пошел на другой заход - создал -помер...

Comment: Та не)) нужно сделать чтоб это все в 2-ч потоках бежало Жена и Муж

Comment: Можно посмотреть [JavaSpecialist Newsletter 188](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue188.html). Там есть два примера: с помощью двух семафоров, и busy-wait на volatile поле. Последний работает значительно быстрее разных блокирующих решений (тем быстрее, чем проще выполняемый код), но страшно ест процессор.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сейчас нет возможности обдумать элегантное решение, но я бы приоритеты задавал. Вот решение в лоб:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(0);
        new Wife(account).start();
        new Husband(account).start();
    }

    public static abstract class FamilyMember extends Thread {

        protected Account mAccount;
        protected String mId;

        public FamilyMember(Account account) {
            mAccount = account;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            startMe();
        }

        protected  abstract void startMe();
    }

    public static class Husband extends FamilyMember {

        public Husband(Account account) {
            super(account);
            mId = getClass().getName();
            mAccount.registerMember(getClass().getName());
        }


        @Override
        protected  void startMe(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    while(!mAccount.CheckPriority(mId))
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Husband " + i + " " + mAccount.deposit(mId));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Wife extends FamilyMember {

        public Wife(Account account) {
            super(account);
            mId = getClass().getName();
            mAccount.registerMember(getClass().getName());
        }

        @Override
        protected  void startMe(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    while(!mAccount.CheckPriority(mId))
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Wife " + i + " " + mAccount.deposit(mId));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Account {

        private int mAccount = 0;

        private List<Member> mMembers = new ArrayList<App.Account.Member>();

        /**
         * проверяем имеет ли член семьи максимальный приоритет
         * @param id
         * @return
         */
        public synchronized boolean CheckPriority(String id){
            Member member = mMembers.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Member::getPriority)).get();
            return member.getId().equals(id);
        }

        public void registerMember(String id){
            mMembers.add(new Member(id, 0));
        }

        public Account(int account) {
            mAccount = account;
        }

        public synchronized int deposit(String id) {
            mAccount += 300;
            // понижаем приоритет
            mMembers.stream().filter(member -> member.mId.equals(id)).findFirst().get().decPriority();
            return mAccount;
        }

        public static class  Member{


            public String mId;
            public int mPriority;

            public Member(String id, int priority){
                mId = id;
                mPriority = priority;
            }

            public void decPriority(){
                mPriority--;
            }

            public int getPriority(){
                return mPriority;
            }

            public String getId(){
                return mId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
Wife 0 300
Husband 0 600
Wife 1 900
Husband 1 1200
Wife 2 1500
Husband 2 1800
Wife 3 2100
Husband 3 2400
Wife 4 2700
Husband 4 3000
Wife 5 3300
Husband 5 3600
Wife 6 3900
Husband 6 4200
Wife 7 4500
Husband 7 4800
Wife 8 5100
Husband 8 5400
Wife 9 5700
Husband 9 6000
```

Потоки, перед тем как внести деньги на счёт, проверяют свой приоритет с помощью `CheckPriority`. Если текущий поток имеет больший приоритет, то вносятся деньги `mAccount.deposit(mId)` и понижается текущий приоритет

```
mMembers.stream().filter(member -> member.mId.equals(id)).findFirst().get().decPriority();
```

Иначе засыпает на 1мс.

Comment: А разве баловаться с приоритетами - не противопоказано в Java? Это вроде чревато.  разные ОС по разному реагируют на приоритетность потоков....Вместо приоритета может проще в акке хранить того, кто последний вносил деньги и если не совпадает чел - пропускать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не меняю приоритет потока. Меняю переменную, которая по смыслу похожа на приоритет.

Answer (score 1):

Пример синхронизации с использованием [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) / [notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account();
        new Thread(new Wife(account)).start();
        new Thread(new Husband(account)).start();
    }
}

public class Account {
    private int account;

    public boolean turn;

    public synchronized int deposit() {
        turn = !turn;

        account += 300;
        return account;
    }
}

public abstract class FamilyMember implements Runnable {
    private final String name;
    protected final Account account;

    public FamilyMember(String name, Account account) {
        this.name = name;
        this.account = account;
    }

    public abstract boolean isMyTurn();

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (account) {
                while (!isMyTurn()) {
                    try {
                        account.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(name + " " + i + " " +  account.deposit());
                account.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Wife extends FamilyMember {
    public Wife(Account account) {
        super("Wife", account);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMyTurn() {
        return !account.turn;
    }
}

public class Husband extends FamilyMember {
    public Husband(Account account) {
        super("Husband", account);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMyTurn() {
        return account.turn;
    }
}
```

В счете храниться флажок `turn`, который определяет, чья очередь класть деньги. Общий код переместился в класс FamilyMember, муж и жена ждут своей очереди с помощью метода `isMyTurn()`.

Конечно, коряво получилось, но представление об использовании `wait()` и `notify()` дает.

---

Это решение похоже на [решение Suvitruf'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491553/199822), только вместо `Thread.sleep()` для ожидания, пока условие не выполниться, используется `wait()`, что эффективнее, так как программа *крепче* спит. Метод `notify()` уведомляет об изменении условия и пробуждает ожидающий поток.

`wait()` нужно использовать в цикле, потому что поток может проснуться и без вызова `notify()`.

---

Вместо флага `account.turn`, наверное, можно использовать значение счета. Если сумма на счете изменилась, то очередь класть деньги переходит к другому. Для этого нужно будет добавить синхронизированный метод `Account.get()`, который будет возвращать текущую сумму на счете. Муж/жена запоминают сумму на счете, после того как доложили деньги, и ждут, пока сумма изменится.

Answer (score -1):

Можно и семафоры. Если с `synchronized` то нужно использовать конструкцию `wait()`/`notify()`: муж делает вклад - жена "спит", жена делает вклад - "засыпает" муж.

Comment: а можно пример кода? Вот допустим на этом сайте ideone.com

Comment: И все равно в данном случае будет нужен объект, через который будет передаваться ход.