# ExecutorService java. Проблема с запуском задач

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня проблема с пониманием запуска задач. У меня есть программа и часть кода должна выполняться раз в сутки, другая же часть кода должна выполняться каждые 20 минут после запуска первой, вот пример

```
Runnable pinger1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(pinger1,0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
};


Runnable pinger2 = new Runnable() {     
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(pinger2,5, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
};
```

Здесь запускаеться `pinger1` раз в сутки, `pinger2` запускается через 5 минут после запуска программы и каждые 20 минут после завершения куска кода в методе `run` - повторяет запуск.

Хочу чтобы второй кусок кода выполнялся не через 5 минут после запуска программы, а через 5 минут после завершения `pinger1` и так чтобы когда пройдут сутки `pinger1` запустился только тогда, когда до конца доработает `pinger2`.

Вообщм алгоритм запуска такой: `pinger1`(выполнение), `pinger2` запуск через 5 минут только после того как завершился `pinger1`
Когда пройдет 1 день и будет время запуска `pinger1` опять, то чтобы он подождал завершение `pinger2` и тогда начал свое віполнение.

Спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется можно прямиком проследовать в один из вопросов и взять оттуда ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491515/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E/#answer-491599

Comment: может проще закидывать `pinger2` в экзекутор в конце `pinger1.run()` и наоборот?

Comment: Ваши задачи независимы друг от друга, соответственно без разделяемого состояния вам не обойтись.