# Синхронизация потоков. Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Столкнулся с задачей реализации вывода потоками на экран информации в строго определенном порядке. Без ограничения общности, пусть каждый поток выводит слово в бесконечном цикле, требуется организовать вывод их на экран в алфавитном порядке.

Как устроить синхронизацию их работы?
Можно, как я понимаю, обращаться к глобальной переменной, её менять, приостанавливать каждый поток при определенных её значениях...

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Можно, наверное, на `Semaphore` сделать. Каждый поток держит два семафора (А и Б), на А он ждет своей очереди на вывод (`A.acquire()`) а второй освобождает после вывода (`Б.release()`) Семафор `Б` для первого потока - это семафор `A` для второго, и т.п. Примерно как [`SemaphoreInterlocker`](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue188.html), только для большего числа потоков. Для двух потоков у нас был [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491515/)

Answer (score 4):

Поройтесь в `java.util.concurrent.synchronizers`. Скорее всего вам понадобится `CountDownLatch` Можно ставить блочить все остальные потоки, пока один поток не дойдет до точки разблокировки. Пошорудить их так, чтобы они поочередно друг друга разблокировали.

А вобще, есть хорошая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/157273/) в которой эту библиотеку подробно разбирают. Не это, так другое найдете.

**UPD** Во! Я все ее искал то! Вот [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277669/) более наглядно и с картинками.

Comment: Если речь про анимашки concurrency, то вот хороший ресурс [Java Concurrent Animated](http://www.jconcurrent.com/). Не помню уже кто на JUG пиарил.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант, который пришел в голову. Каждому потоку даем некоторый порядковый номер, заводим глобальную переменную и последовательно ее искрементируем.

```
public class Solution {

private static int counter = 0;
private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;

public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        Printer printer = new Printer(i, Arrays.toString(Character.toChars(i + 'a')));
        Runnable task = () -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                print(printer);
        };
        new Thread(task).start();

    }

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
}

private static void print(Printer printer) {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        synchronized (Solution.class) {
            if (counter == printer.id) {
                counter = (counter + 1) % THREAD_COUNT;
                System.out.println(printer.word);
            }
        }
    }
}


private static class Printer {
    private final int id;
    private final String word;

    Printer(int id, String word) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```